# why the value of console.log(1 && 2) is 2 instead of true or 1 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had checked for many test cases. It's looking if the first value is true and it's returning the second value.

Example:

```
2 && 5 // --> 5
5 && 10 // --> 10
0 && 2 // --> 0
```

Why doesn't it return either True or 1?

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`

Comment: Logan I approved your change to remove the tag.

Comment: @CodyG. Just saw. Thanks!

Comment: `1 && 2` returns the value `1` if `1`can be coerced into `false`; otherwise, it returns `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description,

> Operator: Logical AND (&&)
>
> Usage: expr1 && expr2
>
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: beat me to it! here's another way to say it as well in the interest of helping people understand `Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value`

Comment: Aren't we supposed to close the duplicates instead of answering them?

Comment: Sure. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-answers-a-low-quality-off-topic-or-duplicate-qu

Comment: @raina77ow you literally can't answer once it's marked duplicate, but if you don't notice that it's a duplicate and answer before that happens, that's not really anyone's fault.

Answer (score 0):

The &&  operator will return the last value if all other values are truthy, otherwise it will return the first non truthy value. So, as in `0 && 2`, `0` is non-truthy, that gets returned.

Comment: Just for fun, two other ways to phrase: 1) `&&` returns the left hand side if it is falsy, otherwise it returns the right hand side. 2) Boolean operators return the first operand that determines the overall result (<- this is maybe harder to grasp, but correct).